# Hadoop Pig customize the key name

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

For example, I have a input file like this:

```
xxx,14
yyy,20
zzz,11
```

I want to SUM for the second filds and output. Now I know how to SUM it by using Hadoop Pig, but I want the output like this:

```
Canada,45
```

So it means that I set the key name to "Canada" by myself and add the SUM as the value. How can I set the key name by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply a constant field:

```
A = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (txt:chararray, num:int);
B = group A ALL;
C = foreach B generate 'Canada' as country:chararray, SUM(A.num) as total:int;
```